# Facebook Graph API and limits

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am working with the Graph API but I have found it to be rather limited. In the news feed on the Facebook website you might see "X and 14 other friends likes Y page." or "X and 3 other friends has changed their profile picture."

In the Graph API it will look like the code below when X and 14 other friends has liked the same page. The Graph API only returns the name of X but not how many friends other than X who have liked the page.

```
{
    application =     {
        id = 01010101;
        name = Pages;
    };
    comments =     {
        count = 0;
    };
    "created_time" = "2011-08-15T08:35:47+0000";
    description = "Description of page.";
    from =     {
        id = 1111;
        name = "X";
    };
    icon = "---";
    id = "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yN/r/xC785tTCIQO.gif";
    link = "http://..../";
    name = "Y";
    picture = "---";
    type = link;
    "updated_time" = "2011-08-15T08:35:47+0000";
}
```

I don't see any way to get this information. Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: Any way you could break down the question to be more concise? It seems like your asking a lot of different things here.

Comment: My question was a bit of a mess, yes. I have shortened it a bit and posted an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of object you are accessing. Recently, Facebook have begun to hide useful info such as who specifically liked something, I'd imagine because they don't want people writing analytics packages for facebook but would prefer users to use the facebook system.

I know when it comes to images you can only get the number of likes , but not who they actually came from.

Your best bet is to use FQL which still lets you retrieve some of this information.

Comment: Thank you very much. FQL seems to be less limited. I will rewrite my application to use FQL instead.

Comment: @steve, these limitations are born out of an abundance of caution on privacy concerns rather than concerns about 3rd party analytics packages. Your point about FQL is true though, FQL is much more flexible.